# How can I call a function when item in combobox changed?

Tags: qt, combobox, qt4

```
connect(ui->ComboBox,SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged()),this,SLOT(switchcall()));
```

in qt, combobox items i have none,server,client.when i select one of this it should call switchcall function.in this function i want to perform task depending upon choice in combobox.how to do it??

Answer (score 22):

You haven't put the args in the `SIGNAL`/`SLOT` statements.

```
connect(ui->ComboBox,SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(const QString&)),
        this,SLOT(switchcall(const QString&)));
```

Alternatively you can use the item index, using the overloaded signal.

Comment: I don't see this overload, but there is a `currentTextChanged` signal in Qt 6.3

Comment: @MasterHD this answer is almost 10 years old... https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#currentIndex-prop

Answer (score 6):

To get the index from QComboBox change event of QComboBox item use:

```
connect(ui->comboBox, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)),
            this, SLOT(indexChanged(int)));
```

in mainwindow.h:

```
private slots:
    void indexChanged(int index);
```

in mainwindow.cpp:

```
void MainWindow::indexChanged(int index)
{
    // Do something here on ComboBox index change
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on the [Qt documentations](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentIndexChanged) the `QOverload<T>::of()` helper function can be used to specify which overloaded signal you're using,

```c
connect(comboBox, QOverload<int>::of(&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged),
    [=](int index){ /* ... */ });
```

Using this convenient helper there is no need to use the old `SIGNAL()` and `SLOT()` syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Use autoconnect:

```
void on_ComboBox_currentIndexChanged(int index);
```

Autoconnect template:

```
on_<control_name>_<signal_name>(<signal params>)
```